# Inserting autocomplete HTML suggestions into the search bar

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, autocomplete

The autocomplete script:

```
const search = document.getElementById('search');
const matchList = document.getElementById('match-list');
let states;

// Get states
const getStates = async () => {
 const res = await fetch('../complete/data/pictures.json');
 states = await res.json();
};

// FIlter states
const searchStates = searchText => {
 // Get matches to current text input
 let matches = states.filter(state => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi');
  return state.title.match(regex);
 });

 // Clear when input or matches are empty
 if (searchText.length === 0) {
  matches = [];
  matchList.innerHTML = '';
 }

 outputHtml(matches);
};

// Show results in HTML
const outputHtml = matches => {
 if (matches.length > 0) {
  const html = matches
   .map(
    match => `<div class="card card-body mb-1">
    <h4>${match.title}</h4>
   </div>`
   )
   .join('');
  matchList.innerHTML = html;
 }
};
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getStates);
search.addEventListener('input', () => searchStates(search.value));
```

The code above generates autocomplete HTML suggestions. I want to add clickable functionality which would insert a clicked html element into the search bar.

The closest I've gotten is this:

```
matchList.addEventListener('click', () => {search.value = matchList.textContent.trim()})
```

While this works if there's only one suggestion, if there's more, all the suggestions are inserted together.

The problem seems to be the fact that `matchList` is an object which returns a single HTML element.
How do I return an object which I can iterate over and place an `onclick` on every HTML suggestion within that object?

Or, how do I return multiple objects, each containing one HTML suggestion on which I can then place an `onclick`?

Or some third option?

Answer (score 0):

```
matchList.addEventListener('click', e => search.value = e.target.textContent.trim())
```